# Looking for a workaround for templatized virtual functions

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

What I'm trying is to have a getter function in a base class that returns a value that only exists in a derived class.

Here's an example of something I'm trying to achieve:

```
class Base
{
    template<typename T>
    virtual T GetData();
};

class Derived_Int : public Base
{
    int data_;
    int GetData() override { return data_ }
};

class Derived_Float : public Base
{
    float data_;
    float GetData() override { return data_ }
};

int main()
{
    Derived_Int A;
    Derived_Float B;
    std::vector<Base*> vec { &A, &B };

    // Somehow get this to work
    vec[0]->GetData();
    vec[1]->GetData();
}
```

The above code doesn't compile it's not possible to have a virtual function be templatized.

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: The provided example doesn't need virtual; as the implementation of `GetData()` is same in both functions. If you have member `data_` declared as `T data_;` in your template class, then your `GetData()` body can have `return data_;`

Comment: shouldn't the `Derived_Float` inherit from `Base`? it could be a typo, still it changes the meaning a lot

Comment: @Wander3r Why don't you make it as an answer, if your know already the workaround/ answer?

Comment: @UsingCpp my guess is that OP could not have given right example for his question.. as my answer doesn't need `Derived_Int` or `Derived_Float` classes to be there at all..

Comment: My bad Derived_Float does indeed inherit from Base. As for @Wander3r's suggestion, will making Base a template class still allow me to achieve upcasting from a derived base<int>* to a Base* class?

Comment: @Wander3r suggestions makes most sense, but if you really want to have polymorphism (virtual) thing, if your compiler supports, may be you can try using something like `std::any` or `std::variant`. For example: ```std::any GetData() override { return std::make_any<float>(data_); }```

Comment: @Wander3r How would you put objects (or pointers to them) of a class template with different template arguments into the same vector?

Comment: @daniel I got the problem with just template. Trying to find a way to put those in the same vector